# Owl carousel destroy don't work

Tags: magento2

I have create an owl carousel with code below

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                "items" : 1,
                "responsive": false,
                "autoPlay": 2000,
                "loop": false,
                "rewind": false,
                "nav": true,
                "navText": ["<", ">"],
                "dots": true
            });
```

and this is output html:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
 <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
   <div class="owl-wrapper">
     <div class="owl-item"></div>
     <div class="owl-item"></div>
     <div class="owl-item"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

when I change to mobile mode. I destroy the owl carousel with code below:

```
$('.owl-carousel').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
```

But it is not destroy. Is there any wrong in my code? or what is the correct way to destroy owl carousel?

Comment: You don't want responsive owl carousel ?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('destroy');
```

Comment: This code will work with latest owl version (from 2.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

and what if we want to save Options before destroying courosel so we can use it at the time of reinitialisation.
i tried $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel().Options() but it doesn't work.